# Testing a sequence of async updates with Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Let's say there's a button that triggers some sort of data processing which takes a while. During processing, I want to tell the user where we are by displaying the messages like "Working...", "Working very hard...", "Almost there...", etc. It is guaranteed that all those messages will appear one after another before the processing is completed. The task is to check this scenario with Protractor.

So, here's an example code:

```
<div ng-controller="AppController">
  <p>{{message}}</p>
  <button type="button" ng-click="go()">Go!</button>
</div>
...
<script>
  angular.module('app', [])
  .controller("AppController", function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.message = "";
    $scope.go = function() {
      $scope.message = "Working...";
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.message = "Working very hard...";
        $timeout(function() {
          $scope.message = "Almost there...";
          $timeout(function() {
            $scope.message = "Done!!!";
          }, 1000);
        }, 1000);          
      }, 1000);
    };
  });
</script>
```

I understand this behavior is relatively easy to test with regular unit tests (Jasmine), yet let's pretend these `$timeout` calls are actually async updates sent by backend via a websocket.

Is it possible to somehow test this sequence of updates with Protractor?

The straightforward approach like this:

```
expect(element(by.binding('message')).getText()).toEqual('Working...');
expect(element(by.binding('message')).getText()).toEqual('Working very hard...');
```

doesn't work. In my case the test fails with:

```
Expected 'Working very hard...' to equal 'Working...'.
```

which is understandable, I assume that Protractor just waits for all pending things to finish before moving on.

One approach I can think of is, explicitly polling the DOM to monitor when element content gets changed. This I would like to avoid. Are there any better options available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give a try to the new feature: [expected conditions](https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/1703) (was added 10 hours ago):

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

var message = element(by.binding('message');

browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(message, 'Working...'), 1000); 
browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(message, 'Working very hard...'), 1000); 
browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(message, 'Almost there...'), 1000); 
browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(message, 'Done!!!'), 1000);
```

Comment: textToBePresentInElement is not working for my case. Please refer    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829169/protractor-wait-command-is-not-able-to-wait-for-the-bootstarp-modal-to-appear