# Protractor wait command is not able to wait for the bootstrap modal to appear

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automation, jasmine, protractor

Scenario: Whenever user sign in using incorrect credentials, a bootstrap modal appears for 1-2 second with message "sorry, incorrect credentials". 
Below is the HTML of the modal.

```
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-body note-error text-center ng-binding"> Sorry, invalid credentials! </div>
</div>
```

I need to verify if the expected error text is equal to actual error text.

My code

PageObject.js

```
var errorModal = element(by.css('.modal-body.note-error.text-center.ng-binding'));

this.getErrorText = function(){

var until = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(until.textToBePresentInElement(errorModal, "Sorry, invalid credentials!"), 3000, "Not able to find");


     return errorModal.getText();

 };
```

Spec.js

```
expect(Login_Page.getErrorText()).toMatch('Sorry, invalid credentials!');
```

Output

> Message:
>       Expected '' to match 'Sorry, invalid credentials!'.

I dont know why this wait is not working.

Comment: Have you tried extracting the text directly using `getText()` ? `return errorModal.getText()`

Comment: yes did that already..

Comment: I have usually seen this issue when there are lot of modal windows in `dom` and at a time only 1(or none) is thrown based on some trigger. But Protractor will always pick up the first one in the `dom`. Can you paste the complete `html` if not ... can you check if you have more than 1 element with `modal-body` in your HTML?

Comment: You can use below mentioned url https://app.p3fy.com/#/login and try login with invalid credentials(offcourse you dont need a valid one :D). I need to capture, the error modal whcih appears. Issue is textToBePresentInElement works well in selenium but not in protractor. I tried with selenium and it worked

Comment: The below mentioned standalone selenium code works well. I mean textToBePresentInElement waits correctly WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(element, "Sorry, invalid credentials!"));
  
  System.out.println("got"+ element.getText());// This printed Sorry, invalid credentials!

Comment: @hello_abhishek .. Thanks for sharing the details .. Can you check my answer below and see if that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer contributed by pittgoose as a part of https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4030. I just thought to share over here

Ok, before every webdriver action protractor performs browser.waitForAngular() which waits for all angular scripts to finish running before performing the next action. In this case I believe protractor is waiting for the popup modal to disappear before it performs its search.

Also, I just proved my theory because when I added browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false) before the browser.wait(...) the test passed. Ex:

```
browser.get('https://app.p3fy.com/#/login');
        element(by.css('[name="email"]')).sendKeys('pittgoose@sampleemail.com');
        element(by.css('[name="password"]')).sendKeys('blah');
        element(by.css('[type="submit"]')).click();
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); // THIS MAKES THE TEST PASS
        browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(element(by.id('errorDialog')), 'Sorry, invalid credentials!'), 3000, 'No!');
```

This would not be an issue with Selenium Webdriver api since it doesn't wait for Angular to load.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the rootCause of the problem after taking a look at your [app]. The error modal you are looking for always exists in `dom` - That means `isPresent()` will always return a true. But it is visible only for 1 or 2 secs on invalid input - That means `isDisplayed()` will return `true` for those only few seconds

The side effect of this is the return value of `getText()`. It returns only visible innerText. Check the below extract from [official documentation](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText)

> Get the visible innerText of this element, including sub-elements,
>   without any leading or trailing whitespace. Visible elements are not
>   hidden by CSS.

Thats the reason you are seeing an empty value from `getText()`

I suggest a work-around where you extract the innerText by `browser.executeScript()`

replace `return errorModal.getText()` with `return browser.executeScript('return arguments[0].textContent',errorModal)` and you should be all good

Let me know if this works

Comment: Thanks for taking time to look into this. Even I am also aware about this workaround, which I earlier tried and it worked browser.executeScript('return (arguments[0].textContent).trim()',errorModal). My main question is why textToBePresentInElement() static method of ExpectedConditions class is not working. I tried the same in selenium webdriver and it worked. I am new to Protractor and am not able to figure it out why this is not working as it still a wrapper over selenium webdriver api. I also posted this in protractor issue https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4030. Please suggest

Comment: The logic for this is simple and standard, I am fetching the text from the errorModal only when it contains the error text by using the expectedconditions textToBePresentInElement() method.

Comment: Your selenium getText() would have been triggered when the pop-up visible for those few seconds. Thats by chance .. Can you run multiple times to see if it is stable...  And you cannot check visibility as `textToBePresentInElement()` uses `presenceOf(elementFinder)` and `visibilityOf()`

Comment: driver.get("https://demo.p3fy.com/#/login");
driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("i.kar@gmail.com"); driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("abhis");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login']/div/div/div/div/div/form/fieldset/div[3]/input")).click();
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='errorDialog']/div/div/div"));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(element, "Sorry, invalid credentials!"));
System.out.println("error text is "+ element.getText());
driver.close();
}

Comment: It runs smoothly everytime because of the explicit wait. If we dont use explicit wait then it becomes unstable. https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_TextToBePresentInElement.htm